# Free domain redirect with simple statistics?

Tags: redirects, analytics, statistics

I wish to redirect my domain to a social media site.
Until now it's been a 301 redirect provided by the domain registrar.

```
Domain -> Social media site
```

But what if I want to collect some simple statistics (initially visitor count would do) of people coming through the domain?

I was thinking about creating a github.io site which contains a Google Analytics (or StatCounter, or 
Histats, or something else) snippet and another redirect.

```
Domain -> github.io (with tracking) -> Social media site
```

Do you think it's a good idea? 
Or is there a cleaner way to achieve this?